# Can't delete Launcher2.apk even on a Rooted Android

Tags: android

I successfully rooted my device and I'm trying to remove Launcher2.apk

Every tool I have tried (both on the device, and using ADB from my PC) says it is deleted successfully yet it still exists!

Yes, I know, why would you want to do that. Well I want to set up our devices to have only our launcher. I know you can set the default but this gets reset every time the app is automatically updated and we can't have that.

Cheers,
Le-roy

Comment: Figured it out. If you are using root explorer then the system folders are mounted as read only. If you click "Mount RW" at the top then it will mount that folder as read/write and you will be able to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to delete a file from a folder which don't have `Write permission`. You have to use `Root Explorer` application in your device and change folders permission. For this you have to do this :

.>> Now go inside of your desire folder.

.>> Now press `Mount R/W` button at the top of folder list.

.>> Now you will be able to delete your file;

Comment: But you can mark this answer as correct answer by clicking on right sign. This would help :)

Comment: I'm a noob :) -just clicked the tick!